# How to get python caller object information?

Tags: python, introspection

How can I fetch the caller object from within a function, and inspect information about that caller?

```python
class A(object):
    def class_A_fun(self):
            print 'caller from class'  # → B
            print 'caller from method'  # → class_B_fun
            print 'caller module'  # → foomodule
            print 'caller instance'  # → obj
            print 'caller object file name or path'  # → 'foomodule.py'

class B(object):
    def class_B_fun(self):    
        obj = A()
        obj.class_A_fun()        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    obj = B()
    obj.class_B_fun()
```

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stefaanlippens.net/python_inspect) is helpful. Google 'python get caller' turns up some nice results.

Comment: What are you trying to do? It's usually not a good idea to do this.

Comment: @phant0m i am trying to develop customized logger Framework,which fetch the object information as shown above.

Answer (score 2):

```py
from inspect import currentframe, getframeinfo, getmodulename
from pathlib import Path


class A(object):
    def class_A_fun(self):
        cuurent_frame = currentframe()
        caller_frame = cuurent_frame.f_back
        filename, lineno, function, code_context, index = getframeinfo(caller_frame)

        # first_arg_name in this case is 'self', but could be sth else
        first_arg_name = caller_frame.f_code.co_varnames[0]
        # f_locals is the local namespace seen by the frame
        caller_instance = caller_frame.f_locals[first_arg_name]

        assert caller_instance is caller_frame.f_back.f_locals['b'] is b
        assert type(caller_instance).__name__ == 'B'
        assert function == caller_frame.f_code.co_name == 'class_B_fun'
        assert filename == caller_frame.f_code.co_filename == __file__
        assert getmodulename(filename) == Path(__file__).stem


class B(object):

    def class_B_fun(self):
        a = A()
        a.class_A_fun()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    b = B()
    b.class_B_fun()
```

Comment: there is nothing that says your caller must have a local called self. that's pure convention (for _methods_ not functions)

Comment: @DavidJones I changed my answer, however there are more complicated situations, e.g. for a static method. In the end one may need to analyze the whole source code to properly identify the calling object.

Answer (score 1):

Not all of those are possible, but most are available by inspecting the call stack:

```python
import sys
import inspect

__metaclass__ = type

class Lorem:
    def ipsum(self):
        caller_frame = sys._getframe(1)
        caller_frameinfo = inspect.getframeinfo(caller_frame)
        print("Caller is in module {module!r}".format(
                module=inspect.getmodule(caller_frame)))
        print("Caller is defined in {path!r}, line {lineno}".format(
                path=inspect.getsourcefile(caller_frame),
                lineno=caller_frameinfo.lineno))

class Dolor:
    def sit_amet(self):
        lorem = Lorem()
        lorem.ipsum()
```

For more information, see the [documentation for the `inspect` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html).

Comment: What about the caller *class*?