# How to check which method called the current method in Python

Tags: python

I have a function `Do` which is called by many other methods. I would like to check inside `Do` function, which method called it and if it was a method from a given list, I would add an `if` statement to not do to something inside `Do`. How can I do that?

Comment: Have you read e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/12997687/3001761? What's the context here, why do you want to do this?

Comment: Having a function behave differently depending on the call site is a recipe for bugs and a maintenance nightmare. Consider splitting this into two functions, or adding an argument to control whether to do the thing you sometimes don't want to do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get python caller object information?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12997687/how-to-get-python-caller-object-information)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `traceback` module will give you access to the current stack with the ability to get the `name` of the caller.

```py
import traceback

def do():
    current_stack = traceback.extract_stack()
    print(f"{ current_stack[-1].name } was called by { current_stack[-2].name }")

def foo():
    do()

def bar():
    do()

foo()
bar()
```

That should give you:

```
do was called by foo
do was called by bar
```

Comment: In my case it returns `module` name (I'm using OOP)

Answer (score 0):

The `inspect` module defines a utility function called `stack` which we can use to retrieve the call stack.

Calling `stack()` returns a list, where the first element is the last call (the function that we call stack() from), the second element is the function that called us, and so on.

Each element returns a `namedtuple`, that has a `function` property, which returns the function name. It means we can get the caller like this:

```
from inspect import stack

stack()[1].function
```

[Check here](https://pythonin1minute.com/who-called-me-how-to-get-the-caller-of-a-function-in-python/) for more details.